# Date comparison in case statement

Tags: ruby

Please help me know, why the output of this is always the else part, even if the first condition gets satisfied

```
  def date_string(date)
    case date
    when date.to_date == Date.today
      "Today"
    when date.to_date == (Date.today - 1.day)
      "Yesterday"
    else
      date.strftime("%dth %B %Y")
    end
  end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @MarekLipka That comes from database (in this case "Thu, 12 Mar 2015")

Comment: `Numeric#day` is a Rails method, you should tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `case` statement incorrectly. It should be:

```
case date.to_date
when Date.today
  'Today'
when Date.yesterday
  'Yesterday'
else
  date.strftime('%dth %B %Y')
end
```

Comment: You can use `Date.yesterday` instead of `Date.today - 1.day`

Comment: I believe you wanted to say: `date.strftime("#{date.day.ordinalize} %B %Y")`

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing at the moment is having case compare the value of "date" with the result of "date.to_date == Date.today", which is a boolean. Something like: "Does date.to_date == true?"

So you can either:

```
case date.to_date
when Date.today 
then ...
```

...or ...

```
case
when date.to_date == Date.today
then ..,
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use the difference in days:

```
case date.to_date - Date.today
when 0
  'Today'
when -1
  'Yesterday'
else
  date.strftime('%dth %B %Y')
end
```